# Read HTML code from file system and show in TYPO3 page

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

**Setup**

I want to transfer data from my project to a TYPO3 instance. Assume I have an HTML export that generates about 20 different HTML files inside my TYPO3 directory. These files contain data from a different system and the data updates quite frequently, so I am overwriting them regularly with the newest information.

**Problem**

I would like to tell TYPO3 to load the HTML contents of each file as its own page. Please note: the pages are not complete html documents (no `<html>` or `<body>` tags). Instead, I want whatever code is in those files to be displayed inside the context of a TYPO3 page. Kind of like a TYPO3 HTML PageContent, but I want the source for the HTML to be from a file.

I don't care if I have to manually set up each page, but I haven't found any way to let a TYPO3 Page or PageContent get its data from a file. Do you know of any way this would be possible?

Note: iframe isn't a solution in my case. I am using TYPO3 7.6.23

Comment: could you use jquery.load() for that?
Another way could be consider each file as a fluid partial. But I guess that this would mean that you have to set a different template for each page.

Comment: Good ideas! jQuery load should work, but I suppose I was hoping there would be a more typo3 native solution. I'm not familiar with fluid partials, but at first glance it looks like a decent workaround.

Comment: as I said, I think that fluid could be a good option. Could you add to your question more details, like the folder structure (where the html files would be, their names...) ?

Comment: I can make the files be wherever I want and name them whatever I want.

Comment: I have a similar problem:  I want to use a html file from disk to show as content inside a page. Any hints for this?

Comment: I think the answer below answers that just fine. If not, maybe open a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on the following assumptions:

1. You have you have a "frontend provider extension" EXT:yourext; if not you can change every path like `EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Etcetera` with the proper ´fileadmin/etcetera/Resources/Private/Etcetera´
2. You use `backend_layout` on database to store the backend layout and use that field to control the frontend template. I don't remember if in version 7 you can also use the filesystem using `key.data=pagelayout`
3. of course you have to adjust the IDs of the backend_layout items
4. the files to include will be partials, stored in the folder `EXT:yorext/Resources/Private/Partials/` and will be named

`MyFileToIncludeOne.html
MyFileToIncludeTwo.html
et cetera`

The basic TypoScript will be something like:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10{

    templateName= TEXT
    templateName.stdWrap {
        cObject = CASE
        cObject {
            key.data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
            key.override.field = backend_layout     
            //I assume you already have some templates  
            1 = TEXT
            1.value = Default

            2 = TEXT
            2.value = Home

            //The layouts for the "pages with html files" begin here
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = MyFileOne

            11 =TEXT
            11.value = MyFileTwo    
        }
    }

    layoutRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:yourext/Resouces/Private/Layouts/Page/  
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:yourext/Resouces/Private/Partials/Page/  
    }
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:yourext/Resouces/Private/Template/Page/  
    }
}
```

So, in the previous lines, 
the template MyFileOne.html will include the partial MyFileToIncludeOne.html, with just writing in it:

```
<f:render partial="MyFileToIncludeOne"/>
```

You could also use distinct paths if you want to keep the files separated:

```
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:yourext/Resouces/Private/Partials/Page/  
        1 =  fileadmin/some/other/path/
    }
```

I hope I have not forgotten important passages. Feel free to ask for clarifications

Comment: That's a very elegant solution to do exactly what I asked about. Thank you so much for writing such a detailed answer! Should definitely be helpful to others who might have the same question.

Comment: If the files change frequently, you would need to make the action non-cachable though, right? Will that be enough to get the partial refreshed on changes?

Comment: I did not thought of that. Maybe https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Render/UncacheViewHelper.html could help?